# Plone windows installation query

Tags: windows-7, plone

I have for the first time tried installing Plone on a Windows 7 machine.  Used the Plone-4.3.1-win32 installer file on a Windows 7 Professional machine.  The setup went off smoothly.  Plone43 directory is present in C:.

However, when i try to access http://localhost:8080 on the same machine via Chrome browser, i get "This webpage is not available" error.  I have added an inbound rule allowing TCP 8080 port to be accessible by all machines.

I have only run the Plone setup file and added the firewall inbound rule.  Is there anything else i need to do before getting Plone running?  Could not find any other documentation regarding this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: look in windows servises and check if zope service is running. you can also ty to run the zope manually from cmd line and check the log

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly the installer includes a shortcut that starts and stops the Plone services for you. Make sure you use it (or use Control Panel - Windows Services as mentioned above) to start Plone, otherwise if it's not running you would indeed be getting that error.